# Subgraph isomorphism problem with linear map

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, np

I am working on proving the NP-hardness of a problem by reducing it from the subgraph isomorphism problem. Currently, I can reduce it from the following problem:

**Problem 1:** Given two graphs $G=(V, E)$ and $H=(V', E')$, is there a subgraph $G_0$ of $G$ that is isomorphism to $H$ under a **linear mapping of vertices**?

But the original subgraph isomorphism problem is defined as:

**Problem 2:** Given two graphs $G=(V, E)$ and $H=(V', E')$, is there a subgraph $G_0$ of $G$ that is isomorphism to $H$ under a **bijection of vertices**?

Can anybody tell me how to further reduce Problem 1 from Problem 2?

Edit: say I have the following graphs where $A_i, b_j \in \mathbb{R}$, and I want to see if there is a linear function parameterized by $\beta$ in the form of $b_j=\beta A_i$ that can make
$G_0$ and $H$ isomorphism.

Note that the figure is just for demo and we don't know if $H$ is a complete graph.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what is meant by "linear mapping of vertices."

Comment: It means that the bijection should be linear

Comment: Sure, but what does "linear" mean, when we're talking about graphs? I know linear $y=ax+b$ from analytic geometry, and I know linear from linear transformations on vector spaces, but I don't know linear for graphs.

Comment: Sorry for this. Let's consider the value of the vertices as in a vector space and then linear means linear transformation

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the value of the vertices". Maybe you can give an example of two graphs, and a linear map between them?

Comment: I add in a figure to explain what I am facing. Hopes this can be better.

Comment: I'm also a little confused-- it seems like either $G_0$ and $H$ are isomorphic or they're not-- there's no linear function that "makes" them isomorphic, right?

Comment: So, are you thinking of the graphs as coming with an embedding in ${\bf R}^2$, and you want a linear operator on ${\bf R}^2$ that takes the one to the other? So, if one graph has a vertex at $(0,0)$, then the other one must, as well? Or do you have some other kind of "linear" in mind?

Comment: Yeah thank you Gerry that is exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it. Anyway, any graph has an uncountable infinity of embeddings in the plane, and most of them won't have a linear map to another, given, graph, so this seems like a difficult property to work with.